# Python requests in an API, pagination only saves the last interation

Tags: python, list, api, pagination

I have this code below, using requests into an API :

```
import requests 

def Sults():
  headers = {
        "Authorization":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    } 
  global id
  id = []
  for count1 in range(3):
    url = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&start={}&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z".format(count1)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    url2 = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z&concluido=false"
    response2 = requests.get(url2, headers=headers)
    data2 = response2.json()
    url3 = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z&concluido=true"
    response3 = requests.get(url3, headers=headers)
    data3 = response3.json()

#   print(data) 
  ids = unidades(data)
  print(ids)
  ids2 = unidades2(data2)
  print(ids2)
  ids3 = unidades3(data3)
  print(ids3)

def unidades(data):
   for i in data['data']:
      id.append(i['id']) #append id list
   return id
    
 

def unidades2(data2): 
  id_exclude = []
  for j in data2['data']:
    id_exclude.append(j['id'])
  return id_exclude 

def unidades3(data3): 
  id_conclude = []
  for k in data3['data']:
    id_conclude.append(k['id'])
  return id_conclude


if __name__ == '__main__':
  Sults()
```

Into the line : url = "https:///api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&start={}&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z".format(count1)  >> this count loops 0,1,2 to the pagination into the api. The problem is that when im trying to save the id from every loop into de list : id =[], the code only saves the last loop, in this case, 3(thrid page of the loop into 0,1,2).

for example : "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&start=0&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z"
Output : [122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 129, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 140, 144, 145, 146, 147, 149, 150, 151, 153, 154, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233]

url = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&start=1&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z"
output about the second page : [234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271]

The output i want is to join both outputs into the id list (in this case page 0 and page 1) : [122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 129, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 140, 144, 145, 146, 147, 149, 150, 151, 153, 154, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just an indentation issue when you are assigning the data  to the id variables.
Your code waits for the loop to finish and then looks to put the data into ids, ids2, ids3 but this will only take the last data retrieved in the data, data2 and data3 variables.
You should just need to move the id bit in one indentation as below

```
def Sults():
  headers = {
        "Authorization":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    } 
  global id
  id = []
  for count1 in range(3):
    url = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&start={}&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z".format(count1)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    url2 = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z&concluido=false"
    response2 = requests.get(url2, headers=headers)
    data2 = response2.json()
    url3 = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z&concluido=true"
    response3 = requests.get(url3, headers=headers)
    data3 = response3.json()

#   print(data) 
    ids = unidades(data)
    print(ids)
    ids2 = unidades2(data2)
    print(ids2)
    ids3 = unidades3(data3)
    print(ids3)
```

This will add the response from each requests to your id variables.

A side note is why are you leaving data2 and data3 within the loop as you will be calling that 3 times unnecessarily as the url you are using stays the same.
What I would change it to is the below, however there may be some reason as to why you do this so ignore the below if needs be

```
def Sults():
  headers = {
        "Authorization":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    } 
  global id
  id = []
  for count1 in range(3):
    url = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&start={}&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z".format(count1)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    
    ids = unidades(data)
    print(ids)

  url2 = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z&concluido=false"
  response2 = requests.get(url2, headers=headers)
  data2 = response2.json()
  url3 = "https://api/api/v1/implantacao/projeto?&dtInicio=2022-01-01T18:02:55Z&concluido=true"
  response3 = requests.get(url3, headers=headers)
  data3 = response3.json()
  
  ids2 = unidades2(data2)
  print(ids2)
  ids3 = unidades3(data3)
  print(ids3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i appreciate bro. I will try this solution. The data2 and data3, in the data2 i want to return the id's from the projects that have been deleted (concluido=false), and in data3, the id's from the projects that have been concluded (concluido=true). 

So i will have 3 lists : 
id > data 1
id > data2
id > data3

I need to exclude the common itens that appears in every list

Comment: You solved, the problem was the identation

Comment: No worries, if you could accept my answer as correct then that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I get your premise around data2 and data3 I just couldn't understand why they needed to be in the loop as there is nothing dynamic within the calls to these apis, hence why I changed the code round in my second code snip